# Invoke Python functions from C# in VS2017

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I am new to Python and currently I have a Python project under VS2017 solution along with a C# project. I know the question has been asked before and the steps involved creating a process in C# and calling the Python.exe and pass in the *.pr file. However, with VS2017 and the integrated Python environment, I want to know if the process of invoking/calling Python functions has been changed/improved? Does it still require me to have Python installed on the server and physically point the location of the Python.exe?

I cannot and will not use IronPython as it is running the dead 2.7 base and I want to use Python 3.6 going forward.

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's still the same. Starting a process is a feature of the .NET language (code) and has nothing to do with Visual Studio.